# Powershell listbox items are sorted wrong

Tags: powershell

The following code gives a listbox where the items are sorted and are sorted wrong.
The items should be in the order they are presented in the collection.
$dag.Sorted = $false clearly doesn't work here.
Does someone have a sollution ?
The item names are in Dutch

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$windows_height = 450
$window_width = 600
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.text = ''
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($window_width, $windows_height)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.Topmost = $true

$dag_hash=@{
  Maandag = 2
  Dinsdag = 3
  Woensdag = 4
  Donderdag = 5
  Vrijdag = 6
}

$dag = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.listbox
$dag.Location = '0, 270'
$dag.Size = '250, 70'
$dag.Sorted = $false
$range = $dag_hash.keys
[void]$dag.Items.AddRange($range)
$dag.SetSelected(0,$true)
$form.Controls.Add($dag)

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Comment: A `Hashtable` is unsorted by definition.  Try using an ordered Hash `$dag_hash=[ordered]@{..}` and remove the sorting stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Theo suggested ad a `odered` attribute to your hashtable definition:

```
$dag_hash=[ordered] @{
  Maandag = 2
  Dinsdag = 3
  Woensdag = 4
  Donderdag = 5
  Vrijdag = 6
}
```